# Blackberry Button not working in HorizontalFieldManager

Tags: blackberry, user-interface

My workFlow is like this ... I have taken Three `HoriZontalManager` one for holding the`BackgroundImage of the button` and two `HoriZontalManager to hold the CustomButton` and i am adding the main hfm which hold the button and the background image at top and then i have added the list in a VerticalfieldManager but i dont get the button Working the focus always remains on the list Field.  Now when **I click on the Button the focus always resides on the First row of the list Field** so it always show me the picker which is actually i have implemented on the first row of listfield. How can i Solve it ..
Thanks in Advanced..

Please help.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.  Instead, _be more specific_.

Comment: Could use some editing, but you have some good info there, so +1 :-)

Comment: Can you provide a reduced test case that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved This issue ... I had to check that if the focus is on the button then do my work else the list field will be invoked and it solved the issue. And it works for touchScreen simulator as well as trackpad devices.

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

    //      if the row select do something with it 
    //      for first row which is time 

    if(backCustomButton.isFocus())  {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new saveScreen());
    }else if (saveCustomButton.isFocus()) {
        Dialog.inform("Save Button on focus");
    }else
    if (_list.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
// Do the ListSpecific things
}
```